# How can I Wrap a SKScene around a SCNNode as its texture?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

I found this peice of code online that allows me to use a scene from SpriteKit as the texture for a SceneKit Node:

```
    labelNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Menlo-Bold")
    labelNode.fontSize = 48
    labelNode.position.y = 50
    labelNode.position.x = 250
    
    skScene.addChild(labelNode)
    
    let plane = SCNPlane(width: 10, height: 2)
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.lightingModel = SCNMaterial.LightingModel.constant
    material.isDoubleSided = true
    material.diffuse.contents = skScene
    plane.materials = [material]
    
    hudNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    hudNode.name = "HUD"
    hudNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: 3.14159265)
    hudNode.position = SCNVector3(x:0, y: -0.3, z: -9.9)
```

I  tried the same code on other nodes other than a plane but it won't work. I'm not sure why, but I'm thinking it's because a SCNPlane is a two-dimensional object.